# Loop through all containers in a blob storage container with ADF

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-blob-storage

I want to loop through all containers in a blob storage account with Azure Data Factory. (Because all data supplying parties have their own container but with the same files). The number of containers will increase during time.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your need could be implemented by Get Metadata Activity simply.

Create DataSet based on your Blob Storage Account Linked Service and don't set any container name.

[image]

Then use [Get Metadata Activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-get-metadata-activity) to get all container names in your account.

[image]

Output:

[image]