# What is the best way to access metadata from my Azure storage account files in Azure Data Factory?

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-data-factory, azure-data-studio

For example, I want to access the following: [Example of what my blob containers look like, I am trying to access the Last Modified date for the name of each folder.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z75BI.png)

In Azure Data Factory, I am able to look at files inside of the container, but I am not able to access the metadata. [Folders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V1niR.png)

Any idea on how to access the data within Azure Data Factory?

I tried trying to query the blob containers but it doesn't appear as if there is a path to do so.

---

How can I secure a list of all the blob containers in my server?

[Container syntax](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XFeRH.png)

Answer (score 0):

To access the Last Modified date for the name of each folder follow below steps:

- First take get metadata activity to get list of folders from container.
  [image]
  Dataset for this:
  [image]
- Pass the output of this get metadata activity to Foreach activity.
  [image]
- Under this foreach take another get metadata to get foldername and last modified date for it.
  [image]
  dataset parameter for it:
  [image]
  Dataset for this:
  [image]
- Now take append variable and save the  foldername and last modified date for each folder with expression `@json(concat('{"itemName": "',activity('Get Metadata2').output.itemName,'","lastModified": "',activity('Get Metadata2').output.lastModified,'", }'))`
  [image]

***OUTPUT:***

[image]

Comment: Wow, thank you for the help. I just have one snag / question. If I am trying to secure a list of all the blob containers to sift through, what should the syntax be for having the whole list provided?

Comment: For example, what should I be putting in the "Container" path to just secure a list of ALL containers (I added a screenshot in the original post).

Comment: I tried to wildcard the container list but that doesn't work.

Comment: check this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61096991/loop-through-all-containers-in-a-blob-storage-container-with-adf) to loop on all containers.